# Compiling vim-gnome with ruby support

Tags: 11.04, compiling, vim, gvim

I followed [this blog post](http://kresimirbojcic.com/2011/05/14/installing-command-t-ubunutu-11.04-ruby-1.9.2.html) to compile gvim with ruby support. However, when I `make`, I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lruby-static
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
link.sh: Linking failed
make[1]: *** [vim] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ramon/vim/src'
make: *** [first] Error 2
```

I searched around for people who had this problem, and couldn't find any. [This guy](http://beans.seartipy.com/2006/09/22/develop-ruby-applications-using-vim-70-editor/#comment-850) just changed computers altogether.

And yes, I have ruby:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i686-linux]
```

**What do I do?**

Answer (score 2):

Compiling things which link to `something` usually requires `something-dev` package installed. Do you have `ruby-dev` installed?

```
apt-get install ruby-dev
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

[According to this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/vim-ruby), you're set - just install `vim-gnome` or `vim-gtk`and you'll have gvim with Ruby support. No need to compile it yourself.

Comment: Thanks jrg, but like [the post I mentioned above](http://kresimirbojcic.com/2011/05/14/installing-command-t-ubunutu-11.04-ruby-1.9.2.html) talks about, a lot of crashing occurred with the version that 11.04 comes with.

Comment: @Ramon I've been using gvim since alpha 1 of 11.04, and I've never had any crashes. It might be something in your  `~/.vimrc` or `~/.vim/*` files.

Answer (score 0):

Update for Ubuntu 18.04... to get Ruby support I had to uninstall `vim-gtk3` and `vim-gnome`. Here's a list of ok-to-install packages. With only these, `+ruby` shows in `vim --version | grep ruby` and [Command-T](https://github.com/wincent/command-t) works.

```
$ dpkg -l '*vim*'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name              Version             Architecture Description
+++-=================-===================-============-===================================================================
un  gvim              <none>              <none>       (no description available)
ii  vim               2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1 amd64        Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor
un  vim-addon-manager <none>              <none>       (no description available)
un  vim-athena        <none>              <none>       (no description available)
ii  vim-common        2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1 all          Vi IMproved - Common files
un  vim-doc           <none>              <none>       (no description available)
un  vim-gnome         <none>              <none>       (no description available)
ii  vim-gtk           2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1 amd64        Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - with GTK2 GUI
un  vim-gtk3          <none>              <none>       (no description available)
ii  vim-gui-common    2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1 all          Vi IMproved - Common GUI files
un  vim-lua           <none>              <none>       (no description available)
ii  vim-nox           2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1 amd64        Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - with scripting languages support
un  vim-perl          <none>              <none>       (no description available)
un  vim-python        <none>              <none>       (no description available)
un  vim-ruby          <none>              <none>       (no description available)
ii  vim-runtime       2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1 all          Vi IMproved - Runtime files
un  vim-scripts       <none>              <none>       (no description available)
un  vim-tcl           <none>              <none>       (no description available)
ii  vim-tiny          2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1 amd64        Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - compact version
```